# Collections within documents in firebase and angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular7

I have the following code to obtain two observables in one and be able to manipulate them.

```
public products: any;


ngOnInit() {
        this.products = this.productService.products().snapshotChanges().map(productSnaps => {
          return productSnaps.map(product => {
            const productData = product.payload.doc.data();
            const productId = product.payload.doc.id;
            return this.productService.getProductImages(productId).snapshotChanges().map(uploadSnap => {
              let number = 0;
              return uploadSnap.map(upload => {
                if(number == 0) {
                  number++;
                  return upload.payload.doc.data();
                }
              })
            })
            .map(uploads => {
              return {productId, ...productData, uploads: uploads};
            })
          })
        })
        .flatMap(products => Observable.combineLatest(products));
      }
```

The services of products() and getProductImages() are the following:

```
type productsCollection = AngularFirestoreCollection<Product[]>;

products(): productsCollection {
    return this.afs.collection<Product[]>('products');
  }

getProductImages(productId: string) {
    return this.afs.doc<Product>(`products/${productId}`).collection('uploads');
  }
```

I have a base in firebase with the following structure:
[my estructur of firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVrql.jpg)

But it does not compile me with rxjs 6, I tried to do it like this:

```
ngOnInit() {    
    this.products = this.productService.products().snapshotChanges().pipe(map(productSnaps => {      
        return productSnaps.map(product => {          
          const productData = product.payload.doc.data();
          const productId = product.payload.doc.id;

          return this.productService.getProductImages(productId).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(uploadSnap => {
              let number = 0;
              return uploadSnap.map(upload => {
                if (number === 0) {
                  number++;
                  return upload.payload.doc.data();
                }
              });
            }),
            map(uploads => {
              return {productId, ...productData, uploads: uploads};
            })
          );
        });

      })
    ).flatMap(products => Observable.combineLatest(products));    
  }
```

But mark the flatMap and the combineLatest error

What at the end of accounts I need is that in the variable products both the documents of the collection "products" are stored as well as the collection that is inside each document and that contains the images of these.

and be able to use them like this:

```
<img height="250" *ngIf="product.uploads[0]" mat-card-image [src]="product.uploads[0].url" />
<mat-card-title>{{ product.name }}</mat-card-title>
```

tanks for you help!.